# Webpack - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'node_modules\chokidar\lib'

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, chokidar

When I compile my Electron application with the npm package "Electron-reload". I got an error.
Apprently, Electron-reload use chokidar to watch my applications files, so It can reload it when a file change is detected.

The error I have when compiling my electron main process with webpack :

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fsevents' in 
'C:\[...]\node_modules\chokidar\lib'
```

And the error I have when my electron application is running :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
 at Object.eval (webpack:///./node_modules/electron-reload/main.js?:12:32)
 at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/electron-reload/main.js?:86:30)
 at Object../node_modules/electron-reload/main.js (C:\[...]\Dist\Electron\app.js:322:1)
 at __webpack_require__ (C:\[...]\Dist\Electron\app.js:20:30)
 at eval (webpack:///./Electron/app.ts?:5:5)
 at Object../Electron/app.ts (C:\[...]\Dist\Electron\app.js:109:1)
 at __webpack_require__ (C:[...]\Dist\Electron\app.js:20:30)
 at C:\[...]\Dist\Electron\app.js:84:18
 at Object.<anonymous> (C:\[...]\Dist\Electron\app.js:87:10)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:30)
```

I can't find anything useful online from Electron-reload, chokidar or webpack. Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./Electron/app.ts",
    target: "electron-main",
    module: "es6",
    watch: true,
    stats: 'minimal',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./Dist/Electron/"),
        filename: "app.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                include: /Electron/,
            },
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    }
}
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I didn't resolved the original problem. But since I only wanted to reload my electron render process when a file is changed, I found another way of doing it without "Electron-Reload"

Inside the function that render my main window I added :

```
import {join} from 'path';
import {watch} from 'fs';

app.whenReady().then(()=>{
   watch('./Dist/Client/', (eventType, filename)=>{ win.reload(); })
}
```

Everything is working fine now.

Comment: From what I read, the `watch` is less reliable, but I think I'm going the same way...

Comment: Yeah, this worked for me at least on windows. Will check on mac too. I'm not using electron-reload, I'm using chokidar directly.